# How do i add extrusions to a mesh with Sub-D without deforming the shape?

Tags: modeling

[image]

[image]

I want to make an inwards extrusion along the red line but whenever I add loop cuts the shape of the rounded part changes. I know that's how support loops work but how do I add detail to a subdivided object?

Comment: once you've added the edge loop, move it a bit to correct the shape?

Comment: @moonboots the shape would still change though

Comment: you could duplicate your shape, create the edge loop on the duplicated version, make it stick to the right shape with a shrinkwrap modifier with the original as target